# Send images from EC2 container in API to a front app

Tags: node.js, express, file, amazon-ec2, multer

I have an API maded with express allowed in a EC2 container.
Also theres an app that use this API to get some post or users data.
When they upload images i use multer to save them in a folder in the project, and save the name of image in a MySQL databa, but i dont know how to send the image to front app, o how they can get the image from container.
This is my folders arch:

[image: Arch of files in a express app allowed in a ubuntu EC2 container]

Answer (score 0):

use `express-static` on images directory https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html on images directory or installing `nginx` or `apache` and serve images directory